# Do i need to manually stop a handler?

Tags: kotlin, handler, repeat

I'm currently building a single activity with single MainFragment page app
The app is used to create alarms using premade templets.
I'm using the Handler+Runnable approach to create the repeating tick every 1 second.

I'm thinking of restart/end the repeater using

```
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
```

during onCreate onDestroy live cycle, but I'm not sure if it's necessary.

I created the handler at the beginning of the viewModel

```
val handler = Handler()
val runnable:Runnable = object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        tick()
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
    }
}
```

and then started it at the init block

```
init{
    handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000)
}
```

While what I'm doing is working out just fine (it continues to tick even in the background) I'm a bit afraid of causing leak since I do not know if the repeating event is terminated after the app is shutdown. 
TBH I don't even understand what handler is exactly yet.